# Only half of my images display. Why?

Tags: html

I want to display four images - two on row one and two underneath.

Only the top row displays for some reason and I just cannot see why.

Here is the very simple code:

```
<img class="social" src="http://www.c5d.co.uk/racenight.png" alt="Race Night">
<img class="social2" src="http://www.c5d.co.uk/mothersday.png" alt="Mothers' Day>
<p>
<img class="social" src="http://www.c5d.co.uk/carlosax.png" alt="Carlo Sax>
<img class="social2" src="http://www.c5d.co.uk/eastersunday.png" alt="Easter Sunday"></p>
```

The web page is:  http://www.c5d.co.uk/socialeventsfour.php

Why don't the lower two images display?

Comment: u missed the quotes in the alt attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img class="social" src="http://www.c5d.co.uk/racenight.png" alt="Race Night" />
<img class="social2" src="http://www.c5d.co.uk/mothersday.png" alt="Mothers' Day" />
<p>
  <img class="social" src="http://www.c5d.co.uk/carlosax.png" alt="Carlo Sax" />
  <img class="social2" src="http://www.c5d.co.uk/eastersunday.png" alt="Easter Sunday" />
</p>
```

You may use `/>` when using images(`img`). Along with the obvious missing `"` from your `alt` attribute.

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple like the missing ", but you know how it is when you have looked at something for ages !

Thanks for the response

Comment: also HTML5 http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/img.html An img element must have a start tag but `must not` have an end tag.

Comment: @SiGanteng http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/syntax.html#syntax-start-tags **#05** - Optionally, a "/" character, which may be present only if the element is a void element.

Comment: Yeah, it's `optional`, not `should always use`, they imply two different meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Because you forget to close `"Mothers' Day` and `"Carlo Sax` on your second and third `<img>`

Here's the corrected one:

http://jsfiddle.net/ytmvy/2/

```
<img class="social" src="http://www.c5d.co.uk/racenight.png" alt="Race Night">
<img class="social2" src="http://www.c5d.co.uk/mothersday.png" alt="Mothers' Day">
<p>
    <img class="social" src="http://www.c5d.co.uk/carlosax.png" alt="Carlo Sax">
    <img class="social2" src="http://www.c5d.co.uk/eastersunday.png" alt="Easter Sunday">
</p>
```

Comment: @IamStalker I'm just following the OP's question, and what do you mean by not correct HTML? HTML5 still has it as far as I know

Comment: If I don't use a <p> or a <br> it doesn't render properly, the right hand image on the second row doesn't align under the one on the first row.

What would you suggest I use please ?

Comment: `<img>` is perfectly valid inside a `<p>`, I don't know where people get that kind of impression... See here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1 `The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself).`, then the list of all block elements here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements. I don't see `<img>` listed there.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I had never come across that before !

Antony

Comment: thank you for your correction, i've deleted the comment, ohhh and i haven't touched your carma.